# Android ZTE Blade III camera intent not returning with data

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, storage

I have a problem regarding `onActivityResult` not being called after opening camera from an intent:

```
Intent takeIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

With extra:

```
takeIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

On ZTE Blade III I am able to open camera, but then when I press 'tick' nothing happens, as if there was some exception in Camera itself, and the control doesn't return to calling activity - onActivityResult doesn't get called.

On other phones with never systems (ZTE is 4.0.4) everything works fine. I am also able to add "return-data" extra to the Intent but then I get thumbnail as result, which I don't want.

PS. photoFile was created the following way:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    photoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wanted to add a comment but i don't have enough reputation.

did you check for null-ness of the file? before using it
did you check if the file exists?
did you check for external storage state? to see whether media state is mounted.

also i suspect the way you are creating your file

can you try using `new File('path/for/storage')` or its sisters?